# Code igniter store goCart not accessing any controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to add a store to my already exisiting code igniter install , however I'd rather not try to add it to my exisiting code ignitor but rather just drop [gocart](http://gocartdv.com/) into a sub directory /store .

I got it all installed and worked out the .htaccess file needed a ? after index.php in order to get rid of the no input file recognized, that seemed to fix the no input file 404 error however now when i try to go to any controller for gocart it shows the same page. here is a link to the test store [link](http://www.lclamar.com/store) , If you click on login or view my cart nothing really changes or shows any other view it seems.  Kinda lost as this all worked on localhost fine with the exact same site build.

my .htaccess file looks like this and seems to work to get rid of the no input error but now wont handle any other controller proplerly or anything.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /store
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

And even this style of .htaccess as well...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas for testing or finding whats going on?

Comment: From my experiences of running codeigniter out of a subfolder, you will definately need the subfolder included in the .htaccess, as per your second example. You will also need to change the base url in the config.php to `http://yoursite/store/`. If you can't change the base URL, then you will need to create routes for all your controllers including /store/ in them.

Comment: hey thanks @Jeemusu I actually think i just got it working properly. I did edit the base URL like you mentioned but what made it work was to change the $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; instead of 'PATH_INFO'  , for some reason i thought goCart would default this to AUTO but from the looks of it, it was deafulted to PATH_INFO. Voila it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer that seems to work in my case.   I did edit the base URL like mentioned in the comments above but what made it work was to change uri_protocol to AUTO in the gocart/config/config.php file.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

instead of

```
$config['uri_protocol'] =  'PATH_INFO'
```

for some reason i thought goCart would default this to AUTO but from the looks of it, it was defaulted to PATH_INFO. Voila it works.  Silly me I over looked that tid bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add access exclusion to some directory, try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|store)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this and in my case it did not change anything for me. I did find the answer which i posted below. Thanks for your suggestion.